# Ajusting as3 code to trigger on mouse event

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, mouseevent, 2d-games, stopwatch

Hi I found this really useful code for a timer counter, however it starts when I play the file. What I need is a way to change this into a MouseEvent.CLICK so it starts when the user presses a button and it stops when the uses presses another button. Is this do able?

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTickHandler);
var timerCount:int = 0;

function timerTickHandler(Event:TimerEvent):void
{
timerCount += 100;
toTimeCode(timerCount);
}

function toTimeCode(milliseconds:int) : void {
//create a date object using the elapsed milliseconds
var time:Date = new Date(milliseconds);

//define minutes/seconds/mseconds
var hours:String = String(time.hours);
var minutes:String = String(time.minutes);
var seconds:String = String(time.seconds);
var miliseconds:String = String(Math.round(time.milliseconds)/100);

//add zero if neccecary, for example: 2:3.5 becomes 02:03.5
hours = (hours.length != 2) ? '0'+hours : hours;
minutes = (minutes.length != 2) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds.length != 2) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;

//display elapsed time on in a textfield on stage
timer_txt.text = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds+"." + miliseconds;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to use `timer.stop()` and `timer.start()`. This won't be perfectly accurate, as calling `stop()` and `start()` basically restarts the current delay (100ms), but if that's good enough then it should work.

Also note that the timer code isn't perfectly accurate as is, since `Timer` events are dispatched with slight offsets based on framerate and script execution time. For an accurate timer you need to poll `getTimer()`, but pausing and resuming becomes a little more complicated to implement.